Result template
I'm a bit new to templates in C++ (I'm mostly a C guy) and wanted to see if I could create a result template.
What I want to know is if there are any pitfalls/oversights in my code.  You can assume that the types R and E represent types with a "default constructor".  That is, R res; and E err; can both be assumed to be valid declarations (e.g., integers, pointers).
template <typename R, typename E> class Result
{
public:
    Result<R, E>(const Result<R, E> &other) : has_result(other.has_result), res(res), err(err) {}

    inline static Result<R, E>
    withResult(R res)
    {
        Result<R, E> ret;

        ret.res = res;
        ret.has_result = true;
        return ret;
    }

    inline static Result<R, E>
    withError(E err)
    {
        Result<R, E> ret;

        ret.err = err;
        ret.has_result = false;
        return ret;
    }

    inline bool
    hasResult() const
    {
        return has_result;
    }

    inline R
    result() const
    {
        return res;
    }

    inline E
    error() const
    {
        return err;
    }

private:
    bool has_result;
    R res;
    E err;
};


Is this intended to be a re-invention of std::expected?  What's the point?

I’m practicing my knowledge of templates. Also, my team compiles for C++11.

I think it's a good excercise to try to implement something like this yourself, as then you will undoubtedly learn more about the language. C++23 introduced std::expected, which we will compare your Result type to.
Let's start with the most important difference:
The constructors are problematic
Sure, std::expected has a lot of constructor overloads, whereas you have static member functions that construct Result objects. That is however not a problem. There are two main problems with your constructors:

You take R and E by value
The constructors take either an R or an E by value, and copy that into the appropriate member function. That means that you only allow those to be copyable types, and furthermore, up to two copies are made each time:

When copying the R or E into the constructor's parameter
When copying that into ret.res or ret.err

Better would be to use perfect forwarding to "emplace" a value:
template<typename... Args>
static Result withResult(Args&&... args) {
    Result ret;
    ret.res = R{std::forward<Args>(args)...};
    ret.has_result = true;
    return ret;
}

Now it's potentially just a few move operations. Even better would be to create constructor overloads, as then you can avoid the move assignment of res.ret entirely, allowing you to support non-movable types.

You store both R and E by value
A Result always contains both a valid R and E object, at least one of which is default-constructed. Even if you only allow default-constructible types, that is problematic, since default constructors and destructors can have side-effects. When creating an error result for example, you do not expect there to be any construction of a non-error result object.
Most implementations of std::expected solve this by using a std::variant<R, E> under the hood. You can implement a variant type yourself in C++11, but it's a lot of work. A less efficient but simpler method is to use std::unique_ptrs to only store an R or E if necessary:
template <typename R, typename E> class Result
{
    public:
    …
    template<typename... Args>
    static Result withResult(Args&&... args) {
        Result ret;
        ret.res = std::make_unique<R>(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }

    bool hasResult() const {
        return ret.res;
    }

    R result() const {
        return *ret.res;
    }
    …
    private:
    std::unique_ptr<R> res;
    std::unique_ptr<E> err;
};



Other issues
There are lots of minor issues with your code:

Unnecessary use of inline. Member functions defined inside a class are inline by default.
Unnecessary use of <R, E> inside the template. It already knows the template types are R and E, you don't have to repeat that.
Use = default for the constructor. It does the same as a default copy constructor does, so you can avoid writing it out by hand.
Missing default constructor, move constructor, missing assignment operators. Because you explicitly declared the copy constructor, the others are no longer automatically generated. Have a look at the rule of three/five/zero.
result() and error() return copies. Consider returning a reference to the stored values instead.

Try implementing the interface of std::expected
Have a look at the interface of std::expected, and try implementing as much of it as possible, and try to understand why it has the interface it has.
Note that you do not have to implement the storage of R and E exactly the same way as std::expected does; getting that right is a lot harder with just C++11.

When you say that std::expected uses a std::variant<R, E>, I guess you mean that's what the implementations usually do, rather than that being the mandated way to do it?  I think that one could reasonably use a plain union, for example.

@TobySpeight having a variant is far more straightforward as it manages a lot of bureaucracy, which you'd have to write and debug yourself with a union.

@ALX23z, I agree that it's the easiest route for implementers - just questioning whether it's mandated.  And since the question is C++11, implementing std::variant would involve that work anyway.
